# ngen и динамическая загрузка сборок

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Есть приложение. В нем в зависимости от неких параметров подымаются формы из dll, которые подгружаются динамически с помощью

> Assembly.Load("Library1.dll");

Мне нужно с помощью Ngen скомпилировать эти сборки в машинные образы

> ngen install MyApp.exe

Но проблема в том что MyApp.exe физически не ссылается на эти сборки, и соответственно машинные образы к ним не создаются.
Можно ли как то обойти это?

Comment: А нельзя просто запустить ngen на нужных библиотеках?

Comment: Можно, но образ создается не самой библиотеки, а тех на кого она ссылается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался.
Если таким вот так создать машинный образ

> ngen install Library1.dll

То он успешно создается, но чтобы приложение видело этот образ в c:\Windows\assembly\  - эта библиотека обязательно должна лежать рядом с исполняемым файлом, даже если она грузится с помощью метода Assembly.Load

Comment: А как _не_ работало? (Это может быть важно.)

Comment: Если библиотека которая грузится через Assembly.Load("Library1.dll"); не лежит в том же каталоге где и исполняемый файл, то флаг Native не включается. Проверить можно с помощью ProcessHacker на вкладке .Net assemblies

Comment: Понял, спасибо!